# Can multiple calls to setupWithViewPager lead to memory leaks?

Tags: android-design-library

I want a `TabLayout` (from the design library) to be populated with a Firebase query.

I have set up a (state) pager adapter which handles correctly adding and removing pages on the fly (Firebase callbacks `onChild{Added,Removed}()`).
No recycling, but it works.

The tab layout is bridged to the pager adapter using `setupWithViewPager()`. This call works fine when an immutable pager adapter is already populated.

But, when the pager adapter is used live (Firebase query), it doesn't propagate its modifications to the tab layout, unless I call `setupWithViewPager()` every time I call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Hence my question, can multiple calls to setupWithViewPager lead to memory leaks?

What is surprising is that there is no way to undo a previous call to `setupWithViewPager()` (`setupWithViewPager(null)` is not allowed).

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: It would probably be better if you posted some substantial parts of your code, which you suspect to have a memory leak.

Comment: `myTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(myPagerAdapter); myTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(myPagerAdapter);` for instance...

Answer (score 0):

You can try in `onDestroy` or whatever is a good moment to release that, like:

```
viewPager.clearOnPageChangeListeners()
```

And then it will not hold the references to the listeners that `setupWithViewPager` added, and so you can call it multiple times without memory leaks.

What do you think?